# Fuzzy c-mean clustering (FCM)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, package

From these two results for fuzzy c-mean clustering :

```
x=data.frame(v1=c(85 ,99 ,89 ,89 ,99),
v2=c(97 ,90 ,93 ,97 ,90),
v3=c( 85 ,91 ,87 ,91 ,93))


 x
  v1 v2 v3
1 85 97 85
2 99 90 91
3 89 93 87
4 89 97 91
5 99 90 93
```

**1- run FCM without using rbind :**

```
install.packages("e1071")
library("e1071")

result1<-cmeans(x,2,50,verbose=TRUE,method="cmeans")
result1

Fuzzy c-means clustering with 2 clusters

Cluster centers:
        v1       v2       v3
1 98.91535 90.04707 91.97589
2 87.60772 95.65459 87.56601

Memberships:
              1           2
[1,] 0.04968228 0.950317721
[2,] 0.99448901 0.005510993
[3,] 0.06595119 0.934048808
[4,] 0.09525480 0.904745200
[5,] 0.99449849 0.005501515

Closest hard clustering:
[1] 2 1 2 2 1

Available components:
[1] "centers"     "size"        "cluster"     "membership"  "iter"        "withinerror" "call"
```

**2- run FCM by using rbind :**

```
  y<-rbind(x$v1,x$v2,x$v3)
  result2<-cmeans(y,2,50,verbose=TRUE,method="cmeans")
  result2

Fuzzy c-means clustering with 2 clusters

Cluster centers:
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
1 96.7755 90.04519 92.89437 96.88113 90.07599
2 85.0000 95.29537 88.07384 89.92616 96.22153

Memberships:
              1           2
[1,] 0.05805512 0.941944884
[2,] 0.99970715 0.000292848
[3,] 0.12524508 0.874754919

Closest hard clustering:
[1] 2 1 2

Available components:
[1] "centers"     "size"        "cluster"     "membership"  "iter"        "withinerror" "call"
```

**My question is that is `rbind` requires for run FCM or not ? In another manner which results is true for run FCM with or without `rbind` .**

Answer (score 1):

As `?cmeans` tells you, the first argument of the function should be

> [t]he data matrix where columns correspond to variables and rows to
>   observations.

So, if you got three variables and five observations, `cmeans(x,2,50,verbose=TRUE,method="cmeans")` will give you - among other things - the membership values for your five observations. That is: observations/rows 2 and 5 belong to cluster 1, and 1,3,4 to cluster 2 (you requested a 2 cluster solution).

The 2nd approach does not make any sense to me; alone because there is no `x$v4` and no `x$v5`.

Comment: lukeA thnks for your answer , rbind command do same as transpose your data  but  I don`t get which of them are true .due to the 2nd approach I edit  it   .

Comment: I see. However, the answer remains the same. In the end, columns have to be variables and rows have to be observations.

Comment: The first approach is 5 observations on 3 variables. The second is 3 observations on 5 variables. Did you mean to use cbind rather than rbind?